# todo.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

so basically I build a todo list app, using mern stack and whenever I am adding todo it gives me todo.map error.

I have a context from there it is importing some function to fetch!

Whenever someone adds a todo just add it and then call the fetchTodo function to update the todo, but on adding it gives me the error

```js
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import GigContext from '../../context/Gig/GigContext';
import TodoContext from '../../context/Todo/TodoContext';
import AddTodo from './AddTodo';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Todo() {
    const context = useContext(GigContext);
    const Todocontext = useContext(TodoContext);
    const [visiblity, setvisiblity] = useState(false);
    const { fetchTodo, todo } = Todocontext;
    const { getSingleGig, oneGig } = context;

    const { id } = useParams();
    useEffect(() => {
        getSingleGig(id);
        fetchTodo(id);
        console.log(todo);
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <div className="p-6">
                <Link to="/" className="cursor-pointer">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-left mr-2"></i>Go back
                </Link>
                <h1 className="text-4xl font-bold mt-5 text-center">{oneGig.title}</h1>
                <div className="flex justify-center flex-wrap  mt-10 p-2  h-[100%] ">
                    {/* card */}
                    {!todo == [] &&
                        todo.map((e) => {
                            console.log(e);
                            return (
                                <div key={e._id} className="bg-gray-200 w-[80%] h-min p-5 rounded-lg mt-8">
                                    <h4 className="text-start text-xl font-medium">{e.title}</h4>
                                </div>
                            );
                        })}

                    {/* add */}
                </div>
                <div className="w-[100%]  flex justify-center sticky bottom-2 mb-2 mt-20">
                    <button
                        onClick={() => {
                            setvisiblity(true);
                        }}
                        className="w-[70%] h-20 bg-gray-100 rounded-md border-dashed border-black border-2 hover:bg-gray-200 transition-all text-xl">
                        Add <span className="fa-l fa-plus fa-xl ml-2"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <AddTodo visiblity={visiblity} setvisiblity={setvisiblity} id={id} />
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: just replace condition
!todo == []  =>>>> !!todo?.length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this simple condition

```
Array.isArray(todo) ? todo.map() : null
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the condition `!todo == []` to `todo.length`
 to check if the `todo` array is empty or not. 
`!todo == []` checks for strict equality between the negation of todo and an empty array.

---

but you know your endpoint may return an empty array.
 think about it.
 better is to initialize `todo` with `undefined` and check `todo && <>..</>` so you are sure it is the first render